# how to generate list of objects by using a method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, list

i have a class and i want to generate its objects in a list by a button.
here is the class:

```
public class player : Form2
    {
        private List<player> players = new List<player>();
        private string name { get; set; }
        private System.Drawing.Color color { get; set; }

        public void playergenerator(string myname, System.Drawing.Color myColor)
        {
            players.Add(new player() { name = myname, color = myColor });
        }
}
```

the problem is i can't invoke `playergenerator` without an existing object but i want to generate all objects in a list.

how to call `playergenerator` without any problem?

i also tried to use a derived class for generating objects but i had some scope problems.

also tried to make playergenerator static but i faced an error:

> an object reference is required for the nonstatic field method or
>   property

so i'm done. there is nothing i can do about it.

help!!!!!!

p.s:the program is written in winform

Comment: Put your `playergenerator` method outside the `player` class...

Comment: A list of players inside a player? I dont quite understand

Comment: where can i take it. i want to access it in almost every where in my program @MightyBadaboom

Comment: I don't understand question. Your `playergenerator` method seem to add a player into the `List<Player>` inside the current instance. Naturally, for that you must have a current instance....

Answer (score 1):

Create new class `PlayerModel`, with properties `name`, and `color`. Your `player` class will be your UI (Form class) and player model is model class with business rules and state (properties)

```
private List<PlayerModel> players = new List<PlayerModel>();
```

Comment: isn't it against the oop rules? i'm using windows form application by the way

Comment: No. What @Vlado is suggesting is that you follow a MV* pattern which is good OOP design. What you have done here is conflated your model into your view (public class player : Form2). They should be separate. You also probably don't want a list of players inside every player. I think what you're looking for is for the playergenerator method to be static, & return a List<Player> that it generates. That would be a good starting point.

Comment: Actually, based on your experience, @raichiks solution may be easier to implement. Once you understand that, know that you probably want to hide the underlying List<Player> by not exposing it directly & further having Players implement IList & IEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

```
//Declare your player list inside your form
private List<Player> players = new List<Player>();

//Make player a CLASS
public class Player
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public System.Drawing.Color color { get; set; }

    //Declare your class CONSTRUCTOR, like this
    public Player(string name, System.Drawing.Color color)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
    }
}

//NOW, this will work
public void playergenerator(string myname, System.Drawing.Color myColor)
{
    players.Add(new Player(myname, myColor));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i suggest solution. Create a class, to define player

```
 public class player 
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public System.Drawing.Color color { get; set; }
}
```

next create class for players list generating

```
public static class Players
    {
        private static List<player> _players;
        public static List<player> players
        {
            get { return _players; }
            set { _players = value; }
        }
        public static void playergenerator(string myname, System.Drawing.Color myColor)
        {
            if (players == null)
                players = new List<player>();
            players.Add(new player() { name = myname, color = myColor });
        }
    }
```

then add players :

```
Players.playergenerator("playgirl", Color.AliceBlue);
```

and access your list of players

```
  List<player> currentPlayers = Players.players;
```